# How to hide or show a tableView when a button is tapped

Tags: uitableview, button, swift3

I'm trying to show then hide a button when user tapped on a button.
But it can't work at all, but it seems my code is correct in my mind.

Here's my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var oeilButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var clicked: Bool!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        clicked = false
        tableView.isHidden = true // First it is hidden
    }

    @IBAction func oeilAction(_ sender: Any) {
        hideTable()
    }

    func hideTable() {
        if clicked == false {
            clicked = true
            tableView.isHidden = false
        } else {
            clicked = false
            tableView.isHidden = true
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do this? Help please

Comment: What is `clicOeil`? What is `tableViewDeux`? Which one do you want to hide? `tableViewDeux` or `tableView`?

Comment: ok sorry it's because I simplify my code for the post, I just edited it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `hideTable` implementation with:

```
func hideTable() {
    tableView.isHidden.toggle()
}
```

This way you won't need a `click` variable and you won't need to check for anything.

Comment: I was about to post an answer using a ternary. You beat me to it only with less lines of code :)

Comment: U can post it too user3344977, I'm curious with ternary too because I tried with that without success